# how to know where memory is consumed in a process

Tags: c, linux, memory, memory-leaks

I have given a servers process written in C/C++ to debug, which starts with low mem consumption, but its memory keeps growing as we connect more and more client. However, once we disconnect all clients, memory does not come down fully even overnight. It might be some data structure where memory be saved or memory leak, but not sure. Is there any tool which can be used to see where and who is eating that memory (data structure, function module etc.) without using valgrind as it has it own limitation and memory consumption could not be real mem leak. I want to narrow down the issue without analyzing the code.

tried analysing proc system etc

Comment: I've used [VTune](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/oneapi/vtune-profiler.html#gs.vwgf2j) before in Windows,, think it's been ported to linux. But it sounds like client disconnect code is a good place to start, something isn't getting fully cleaned up.

Comment: compile the system using the Sanitizer flags `-fsanitize=leak`. This will report all memory leaks when terminating. That way more easy (and performant!!!) as Valgrind

Comment: What happens the next day? Does the server reuse the memory for new clients, or does it continue to grow? It is not unusual for a program to keep heap memory, anticipating it to be used again in the future.

Comment: It reduces but not at original level and stuck at some point. And when we try to connect new client it becomes too slow. so i am not sure if it is a mem leak of it has to keep clients data in history

Answer (score 0):

While leaksanitizer and addresssanitizer indeed help with finding most of leaks, in your case I would recommend [heaptrack](https://github.com/KDE/heaptrack), because it helps finding what inside program allocates most of memory with callstack. Also you can select time period for analysis inside recorded memory usage.

Answer (score -1):

Guessing, code include malloc block but no free blcok.
And heap area close to death.

Comment: try to find malloc block agorithm.